# Synthetic ferritin models and μ notation

Tags: coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

This is the question verbatim:

> Details of two synthetic models of ferritin are presented below:
>
> #### System 1
>
> $$\begin{multline}\ce{Fe(OAc)2 + LiOMe ->T[in presence of $\ce{O2}$][in MeOH]\\
>  Fe12(OAc)3(\mu-OAc)3(MeOH)4(\mu-OMe)8(\mu_3-OMe)10(\mu_6-O)2}\end{multline}$$
>
> #### System 2
>
> $$\begin{multline}\ce{Fe(O3SCF3)2 + L ->T[in MeOH]\\ [Fe6(OMe)4(\mu-OMe)8(\mu_4-O)2L2][O3SCF3]2}\quad (\ce{L~=~N(CH2CH2NH2)3})\end{multline}$$
>
> How valid are each of these systems as a model of ferritin? Consider
>   both structural and functional features.

I have no idea how to start with this. I wasn't taught what the $\mu$ notation means nor about the structures of ferritin models. I'm guessing $\mu$ denotes a bridging ligand?

I know that oxygen binds very well to Fe, hence why it needs to be carefully controlled around it. The chelating nature of L can't be ignored.

Is the symmetry of the structures important? I know that natural ferritin has 3 and 4-fold symmetry.

Comment: $\mu_6$ means that it bridges six iron atoms.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the courseware, please? A quick look at ferritin structure made me wonder what the authors believe to be a model for ferritin.

Comment: It's not publicly available and has nothing on synthetic ferritin models. It only talks about natural ferritin.